Miscalculating midpoint of 3 objects?
I have a problem with a script which is calculating the middle point of 3 objects A, B and D.
When I move B in between D and A, the C object should be in location of B, but it is a fair amount on opposite side from which the B object moved from.
Below are the lines which i'm using.
a = scene.objects["a"]
b = scene.objects["b"]
d = scene.objects["d"]
c = scene.objects["c"]  
 
aPos = a.position.xyz
bPos = b.position.xyz
dPos = d.position.xyz  
 
mid = (aPos + bPos + dPos) * 0.5
 
c.worldPosition.xyz = mid

Feels like it is not calculating this precisely, and even if i move the mesh of object B to where it supposed to look like, visually B aligns with C between A and D. But when B moves for a fair amount to opposite side again, it no longer feels like it is the middle of A, B and D.
Just wanted to ask if anyone has been facing or noticed this "glitch" I would say, or maybe a more precise way of getting this done exists?
Thanks in advance!

Three points, divide by 3, not two.
mid = (aPos + bPos + dPos) / 3.0


This night the Daniel saved my life with this soooong!
I could be dieing here for years trying to figure this out...
Thank You so much!
